# SQL, convert varchar(255) to mediumint

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP and MySQL. I have a `varchar(255)` column called `MatchingNumbers` contains numbers, like `11111,22222,33333`. These numbers are manually input.
On the other hand, `11111` is also a `mediumint(8)` with other data in the row.
Now I want to pick those numbers out, convert them from `varchar` to `mediumint`, and then display them as per row.

```
number    shape  weight  height  MatchingNumbers
00000     X      10      10      11111,22222,33333  Click to view Matching numbers
11111     X      10      10
```

Now when I click "Click to view Matching numbers" button,
I want to make

```
11111     X      10      10     
22222     X      10      10     
33333     X      10      10
```

Listed one per row. 
Is this possible?

This is the code I thought, but not sure.

```
$number = ctype_digit($_GET['number']) ? $_GET['number'] : "";

$lines = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE Number=\"$number\"");
```

And how can I change string to numeric?

Comment: do you want to  change that in php ?

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode no, keep the varchar(255), convert it to mediumint(8), and pick these numbers

Comment: can mention the query you are corrently working on?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$number = isset($_GET['number']) ? (int)$_GET['number'] : "";
```